# Change text position and stat output in ggscatter- pearson's correlation

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, correlation, ggpubr

I am graphing correlations in ggplot with the r and p values displayed. This line of text prints inside the graph and has some of my data point overlapping. I need to move the text outside of the graph, on top would be fine. I also need to change the "R" to "r". Here is an example of my code for one of my graphs and the output. In the end I will have 7 correlation graphs on the same plot using ggarrange, so they will also be a bit small.

[image]

```
ggscatter(E_A, x = "EROD_Value", y = "AChE_Value", 
          add = "reg.line", conf.int = FALSE, 
          cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
          color = "Region", palette = "jco",
         xlab = " EROD values", ylab = " AChE values", title = "")
```

I have not been able to find any suggested changes to my code online that would address either of these issues under the circumstances. I have seen some sample code and example graphs that print out a lowercase r, but it is essentially the same as what I have here and does not give me the same result.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpubr/versions/0.5.0/topics/ggscatter) it appears that you can use `cor.coeff.args` to define parameters to send to `stat_cor`.  The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpubr/versions/0.4.0/topics/stat_cor) for that function indicates `label.x` and `label.y` control absolute positioning of the label.  So, I'm guessing adding `cor.coeff.args = list(label.x = ... , label.y = ... )` should give you a starting point.

Comment: What is the correlation you want to have in the label? For the whole data set or one of the lines? If you are interested only in correlation then major axis regression could be preferable to ordinary regression. To get more flexibility you may want to have a look at package 'ggpmisc'. Please provide example code that can be run, either include the data or use for the example data available in R or a package.